# Correlation tests in R by groups in many single rows of data

Tags: r, statistics, bigdata, correlation

I would like to perform a series of correlation tests (either Pearson or Spearman will do, but will attempt both if possible) on a large dataset (40,000+ genes), which is arranged as follows in this artificial example:

```
Gene    S1- S2- S3- S4- S5- S1+ S2+ S3+ S4+ S5+
A       3   6   9   12  15  6   9   12  15  18
B       2   1   4   1   3   1   3   4   7   7
C       3   6   9   12  15  18  15  12  9   6
```

I have five paired samples that were split (- and +, for this example). I would like to see if there is any correlation between the (-) and (+) groups for each individual gene (would need both correlation coefficient and p-value). Ergo, for this example, I'd receive:

```
Gene    p-val   corr.
A       0       1
B       0.94    0.04
C       0       -1
```

I've yet to figure out any way to do this in R, but perhaps I'm missing something (only recently began learning how to use the program). If there is another freeware program that could perform these tests more efficiently, I'm open to any option (our university is cheap).

Answer (score 2):

```
dat <- read.table(text="Gene    S1- S2- S3- S4- S5- S1+ S2+ S3+ S4+ S5+
A       3   6   9   12  15  6   9   12  15  18
B       2   1   4   1   3   1   3   4   7   7
C       3   6   9   12  15  18  15  12  9   6 ", header=TRUE)

cbind( dat[,1,drop=FALSE], 
cor.gene= apply(dat[,-1], 1, function(x) cor(x[1:5], x[6:10]) ), 
cor.test= apply(dat[,-1], 1, function(x) cor.test(x[1:5], x[6:10])$p.value ) )
  Gene    cor.gene  cor.test
1    A  1.00000000 0.0000000
2    B  0.04411765 0.9438459
3    C -1.00000000 0.0000000
```

@Henrik wanted only one `apply` , so this being a column oriented language, you need to transpose the result:

```
cbind( dat[,1,drop=FALSE], 
       t( apply(dat[,-1], 1, function(x) 
                               c( cor.gene=cor(x[1:5], x[6:10]), 
                                  pval= cor.test(x[1:5], x[6:10])$p.value ) )
      ) )
  Gene    cor.gene      pval
1    A  1.00000000 0.0000000
2    B  0.04411765 0.9438459
3    C -1.00000000 0.0000000
```

Comment: I think you might change `$statistic` to `$p.value`

Comment: I was about to post a similar solution, so I am slightly curious about the background for the -1?

Comment: Yeah, I was a bit surprised by that. Suspected it was probably from the OP who was expecting a more complete solution than I originally  offered. (Especially since my very first effort had a syntax error.) But I suppose it could have just be a random drive-by shooting.

Comment: :) I started out with one `apply` with `cr <- cor.test(x[1:5], x[6:10])` and `data.frame(cr$p.value, cr$estimate)`. Initially I thought that one `apply` was clean, but it required some additional step afterwards to get all the pieces in place...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your update. I really appreciate it. Far cleaner than my attempt - I learn so many nice solutions. I have already given you my +1 here. I add a symbolic one to your comment.